# Inserting values in SOAP envelope using c#

Tags: c#, .net, soap

I have a formatted SOAP envelope with static values for each tag.
But some tags have placeholders like

```
<Name>{{Name}}</Name>
```

Please let me know how can I insert value for "Name" in Soap envelope using c# code. Thank you.

Comment: [`String.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906224(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`String.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: SOAP means web service. Use WCF instead of trying to construct the SOAP XML by hand. Otherwise, just use String.Replace or a regex.

Comment: By the way, SOAP also means WSDL. *Why* are you using a string template when you can generate a service proxy from the WSDL or XSDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something similar to this:

```
void Main()
{
    string soapMessage = "<Name>{{Name}}</Name>";
    soapMessage = ReplaceToken(soapMessage, "Name", "NameValue");
}

public string ReplaceToken(string soapMessage, string tokenName, string value)
{
    return soapMessage.Replace("{{" + tokenName + "}}", value);
}
```